# Group elements by an array/Collection<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections, grouping

Let's say I have a `Track` class that has a `string[] Genres` property.

How can I efficiently group `Track` elements into genres with one entry being a part of multiple groups if needed? For example, for following collection:

```
A - Rock
B - Pop, Rock
C - Rock, Soundtrack
D - Pop, Soundtrack
```

The result for this should be:

```
Rock - A, B, C
Pop - B, D
Soundtrack - C, D
```

Is there any easy way to do that using LINQ? Or is there a more efficient way than using LINQ alltogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var genresTracks = tracks.SelectMany(track => track.Genres, (track, genre) => new 
                         { 
                             // you might want to correct the Name property
                             // with the correct one.
                             Track = track.Name, 
                             Genre = genre
                         })
                         .GroupBy(tg => tg.Genre)
                         .Select(gr => new 
                         {
                             Genre = gr.Key, 
                             Tracks = gr.Select(x=>x.Track)
                         });

foreach(var genreTracks in genresTracks)
{
    var tracksCsv = string.Join(",", genreTracks.Tracks);
    Console.WriteLine($"{genreTracks.Genre} - {tracksCsv}");
}
```

Initially we flatten our collection using the `SelectMany` method, to a sequence of anonymous objects with two properties, Track - the track's name and Genre - one of the genres, in which this track can be categorized to. So the newly sequence would pe consisted of pairs like ("A","Rock"), ("B","Rock"), ("B","Pop"), etc. Then we `GroupBy` this sequence based on the Genre property, so groups are created with key the Genre and Members the track names. Last we project each group into an object with two properties the `Genre` and the `Tracks`.

Comment: An interesting approach. Thanks!

Comment: I made some changes to your code to better fit the XAML bindings. First of all, I removed the last `.Select()` query. I also changed the `.GroupBy()` query to `.GroupBy(tg => tg.Genre, tg => tg.Track);`. This way I get `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, LibraryEntry>>` as a result of the entire LINQ query.